# Wanting to obfuscate data in database incrementally

Tags: postgresql, obfuscation

I am looking to obfuscate data in a postgres database that is quite large and would like to be able to do it incrementally. What i was thinking, is that I could roll the char's of names forward or something like that, but, I would need a way to be able to tell if it has been applied to that "name" already? any ideas on this? If it could be done this way i.e is_changed(), it would be easy to replay on the difference each day.

I am pretty much wanting to find all first/last /mobile/emails in the db and change them but not into garbage. Also, some names are in jsonb columns just to make it more complicated ;)

Cheers

Comment: Is there a good reason why? Usually some sort of data at rest encryption is preferred and/or keeping your database on a separate server that isn't on a wan or publicly accessible network. I mean if your data is scrambled, you will essentially lose the ability to query on that data easily. And if something is hacked, it won't really do much to help because they can likely just get whatever obfuscation method you created.

Comment: The general idea is to obfuscate but not destroy, so it can be used in development and load-testing environments but still be relatively legible in the UI and loose relationships still be maintained.

Comment: What is the threat profile you're trying to defend against? I agree with @Jonathan above, the kind of obfuscation you're describing here sounds ill-suited to protecting your data. Are you trying to protect your data from a database breach? Protect data exposed to the frontend application?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I have decided to do a text pg_dump and scripted a solution which modifies all relevant data with the same pattern. This allows the relationships to be maintained after the obfuscation has been done.

It is also much simpler and performant than sql + updates across a large dataset.

Still open to other ideas if anyone has a better one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not terribly concerned with how obfuscated the resulting text is, maybe  one of the hashing functions included within postgres would suffice, such as `md5` just for a simple example.

```
 UPDATE person p SET p.name = MD5(p.name::text);
```

A possible *actual* implementation might involve using the `pgcrypto` module to encode your values, this would not be terribly efficient however.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgcrypto.html

```
 UPDATE person p SET p.name = crypt(p.name::text, gen_salt('test'));
```

But as I asked in the comment, what is the threat profile you're trying to guard against? Obfuscation might not be a great solution for mitigating the effects of a data breach.